# Perl: Printing through socket

Tags: perl, sockets

I'm trying to script battleship with perl, which can be played over the network.
The problem is that i'm just able to print on the same console, but not on other consoles through the socket.

Client:

```
$socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
    PeerHost => '127.0.0.1',
    PeerPort => '5005',
    Protocol  => 'tcp'
) or die "Socket konnte nicht erstellt werden!\n$!\n";

print "Client kommuniziert auf Port 5005\n";

while ( $eing ne ".\n" ) {
    $eing = <> ;
    print $socket "$eing";
}
```

Server:

```
$socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
    LocalHost => '127.0.0.1',
    LocalPort => '5005',
    Protocol  => 'tcp',
    Listen   => 5,
    Reuse        => 1   
) or die "Socket konnte nicht erstellt werden!\n$!\n";

while ( 1 ) {
    $client_socket = $socket -> accept();
    $peeraddress   = $client_socket -> peerhost();
    $peerport      = $client_socket -> peerport();

    $eing = "";
    while ( $eing ne ".\n" ) {  
        print "while";
        &ausgabe;
    }
}

sub ausgabe {
    foreach $crt_board (@board2) {
        foreach $spalte (@$crt_board) {
            print $client_socket "$spalte ";    
        }
        print $client_socket "\n";
    }
}
```

The result should be an board which looks like this.

```
   1  2  3  4  5  
1  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  
2  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  
3  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  
4  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  
5  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?
```

Comment: Which output do you expect?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: Hence I desume that you have a "board" input file which you feed to the client, haven't you?

Comment: Its an array instead of an file.

Comment: Where do you actually read from a socket?

Comment: Right now nowhere, cause i thought i dont need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read from a socket if you want transfer data from server to client, or vice versa. Do always use strict (and warnings). The following will get you started:

Client:

```
use strict;
use IO::Socket::INET;

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
    PeerHost => '127.0.0.1',
    PeerPort => '5005',
    Protocol  => 'tcp'
) or die "Socket konnte nicht erstellt werden!\n$!\n";

print "Client kommuniziert auf Port 5005\n";

while ( 1 ) {
    my $data;
    $socket->recv($data, 64);
    print $data;
    last if $data =~ m#\.\n#;
}
```

Server:

```
use strict;
use IO::Socket::INET;

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
    LocalHost => '127.0.0.1',
    LocalPort => '5005',
    Protocol  => 'tcp',
    Listen   => 5,
    Reuse        => 1   
) or die "Socket konnte nicht erstellt werden!\n$!\n";

while ( my $client_socket = $socket -> accept() ) {
    my $peeraddress   = $client_socket -> peerhost();
    my $peerport      = $client_socket -> peerport();

    ausgabe($client_socket);
}

sub ausgabe {
    my $client_socket = shift;
    my @board2 = ([" ", 1,2,3],[1,"?","?","?"],
                  [2,"?","?","?"], [3,"?","?","?"]);
    foreach my $crt_board (@board2) {
        foreach my $spalte (@$crt_board) {
            $client_socket->send("$spalte ");    
        }
        $client_socket->send("\n");
    }
    $client_socket->send(".\n");
}
```